# PreparedStatement not executing the query

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement

I am trying to move all query executions from Statement to PreparedStatement due to SQL injection. My original issue was with update statement, but I wanted to try it with select statement as well. When I execute the below line of code, the statement returns nothing.

```
String selectQuery = "select is_enabled, syllabus_id from ic_syllabus where syllabus_id=?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(selectQuery);
pstmt.setString(1, "25AC1CFB7C1A2CF07F176BD3A296F229");
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
    String flag = rs.getString(1);
    String sybsId = rs.getString(2);
}
```

I am using Oracle database and am not getting any exceptions either.

Comment: Are you certain there is a row in the table that matches the `syllabus_id` you're passing in?  Is `syllabus_id` actually a `varchar2` (normally a column ending in `id` would be an integer)?

Comment: The code doesn't return anything. You need to add `System.out.println` in the if clause and print out the results.